# Transformar 3 classes CSS em uma só

Tags: css, css3, primefaces

Tenho essas 3 classes `css`, e gostaria de saber se é possivel transformar em uma só, ela seria utilizada em `panel grid` do `Primefaces`

```
.panelGridCenter {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.gridNoBackground tr{
    background: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.noBorders tr, .noBorders td {
    border: none !important;
    border-spacing: 0px !important;   
}
```

Estou em dúvida como fazer que que o `panel grid` fique alinhado ao centro e retire a cor de fundo e as bordas dele em um único `css`.

Obrigado

Comment: voce gostaria de escrever todo o código em apenas uma classe, ou gostaria de setar no componente panelgrid uma classe e escrever o css para o tr e td à partir desta `classname` que setou?

Comment: @MichelSimões gostaria de aplicar em uma unica classe aqueles três classes entende.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se sua dúvida for setar um `className` ao componente `panelgrid` e à partir disso implementar as instruções CSS para os `TR` e `TD` do panel, pode fazer da seguinte forma, setando o classname ao panelgrid:

```
.meuPanel{
     margin: 0 auto;
 }
.meuPanel tr{
      background: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;   
}
.meuPanel tr td{
     border: none !important;
     border-spacing: 0px !important;    
}
```

Se voce quer aplicar as tres classes ao mesmo objeto pode fazer separado por espaço:

```
className="classUm classDois classTres"
```

Comment: Não tem como eu criar no arquivo de `CSS` um única classe não?

Comment: coloca todos os atributos dentro da mesma classe e testa.

Comment: Infelizmente não da certo, eu já havia tentado isso mas o que você propõe da certo.

Comment: da um joinha na resposta ai entao...